# How to extract this array?

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

i have code that i assume some of that is not array.
i try to use loop foreach but its invalid.
i extract this code from serialized data,

```
array (
'last_submit' => '1',
'feeds_changed' => '1',
'streams' => '{"id1":{"id":"1","name":"Test Stream","feeds":"[{\\"content\\":\\"testing\\",\\"id\\":\\"tm02801\\",\\"type\\":\\"facebook\\",\\"filter-by-words\\":\\"testing2\\"},{\\"content\\":\\"testing3\\",\\"id\\":\\"oe29415\\",\\"type\\":\\"instagram\\",\\"filter-by-words\\":\\"9gag\\"},{\\"content\\":\\"testing\\",\\"retweets\\":\\"nope\\",\\"replies\\":\\"nope\\",\\"id\\":\\"nq62491\\",\\"type\\":\\"twitter\\",\\"filter-by-words\\":\\"testing\\"},{\\"content\\":\\"testing\\",\\"id\\":\\"nt14171\\",\\"type\\":\\"pinterest\\"}]","posts":"40","cache":"yep","cache-lifetime":"10","private":"nope","hide-on-desktop":"nope","hide-on-mobile":"nope","heading":"Stream Demo","headingcolor":"rgb(154, 78, 141)","subheading":"","subheadingcolor":"rgb(114, 112, 114)","hhalign":"center","bgcolor":"rgb(229, 229, 229)","mobileslider":"nope","viewportin":"yep","layout":"grid","theme":"classic","gc-style":"style-4","width":"260","margin":"20","cardcolor":"rgb(255, 255, 255)","namecolor":"rgb(154, 78, 141)","textcolor":"rgb(85, 85, 85)","linkscolor":"rgb(94, 159, 202)","restcolor":"rgb(132, 118, 129)","shadow":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22)","bcolor":"rgba(240, 237, 231, 0.4)","talign":"left","css":""}}',
'streams_count' => '1',
'consumer_key' => '',
'consumer_secret' => '',
'oauth_access_token' => '',
'oauth_access_token_secret' => '',
'instagram_access_token' => '',
)
```

but how to get value in **stream** value bellow?,

```
'streams' => '{"id1":{"id":"1","name":"Test Stream","feeds":"[{\\"content\\":\\"testing\\",\\"id\\":\\"tm02801\\",\\"type\\":\\"facebook\\",\\"filter-by-words\\":\\"testing2\\"},{\\"content\\":\\"testing3\\",\\"id\\":\\"oe29415\\",\\"type\\":\\"instagram\\",\\"filter-by-words\\":\\"9gag\\"},{\\"content\\":\\"testing\\",\\"retweets\\":\\"nope\\",\\"replies\\":\\"nope\\",\\"id\\":\\"nq62491\\",\\"type\\":\\"twitter\\",\\"filter-by-words\\":\\"testing\\"},{\\"content\\":\\"testing\\",\\"id\\":\\"nt14171\\",\\"type\\":\\"pinterest\\"}]","posts":"40","cache":"yep","cache-lifetime":"10","private":"nope","hide-on-desktop":"nope","hide-on-mobile":"nope","heading":"Stream Demo","headingcolor":"rgb(154, 78, 141)","subheading":"","subheadingcolor":"rgb(114, 112, 114)","hhalign":"center","bgcolor":"rgb(229, 229, 229)","mobileslider":"nope","viewportin":"yep","layout":"grid","theme":"classic","gc-style":"style-4","width":"260","margin":"20","cardcolor":"rgb(255, 255, 255)","namecolor":"rgb(154, 78, 141)","textcolor":"rgb(85, 85, 85)","linkscolor":"rgb(94, 159, 202)","restcolor":"rgb(132, 118, 129)","shadow":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22)","bcolor":"rgba(240, 237, 231, 0.4)","talign":"left","css":""}}',
```

Comment: Take a look at phps `json_decode()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php Note, that you will get returned an _object_, not an _array_, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json_decode() can help you. use this function to get access the **stream** key of your array.

```
$array = array (
    'last_submit' => '1',
    'feeds_changed' => '1',
    'streams' => '{"id1":{"id":"1","name":"Test Stream","feeds":"[{\\"content\\":\\"testing\\",\\"id\\":\\"tm02801\\",\\"type\\":\\"facebook\\",\\"filter-by-words\\":\\"testing2\\"},{\\"content\\":\\"testing3\\",\\"id\\":\\"oe29415\\",\\"type\\":\\"instagram\\",\\"filter-by-words\\":\\"9gag\\"},{\\"content\\":\\"testing\\",\\"retweets\\":\\"nope\\",\\"replies\\":\\"nope\\",\\"id\\":\\"nq62491\\",\\"type\\":\\"twitter\\",\\"filter-by-words\\":\\"testing\\"},{\\"content\\":\\"testing\\",\\"id\\":\\"nt14171\\",\\"type\\":\\"pinterest\\"}]","posts":"40","cache":"yep","cache-lifetime":"10","private":"nope","hide-on-desktop":"nope","hide-on-mobile":"nope","heading":"Stream Demo","headingcolor":"rgb(154, 78, 141)","subheading":"","subheadingcolor":"rgb(114, 112, 114)","hhalign":"center","bgcolor":"rgb(229, 229, 229)","mobileslider":"nope","viewportin":"yep","layout":"grid","theme":"classic","gc-style":"style-4","width":"260","margin":"20","cardcolor":"rgb(255, 255, 255)","namecolor":"rgb(154, 78, 141)","textcolor":"rgb(85, 85, 85)","linkscolor":"rgb(94, 159, 202)","restcolor":"rgb(132, 118, 129)","shadow":"rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22)","bcolor":"rgba(240, 237, 231, 0.4)","talign":"left","css":""}}',
    'streams_count' => '1',
    'consumer_key' => '',
    'consumer_secret' => '',
    'oauth_access_token' => '',
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => '',
    'instagram_access_token' => '',
);

$json = json_decode($array['streams']);

echo $json->id1->name; // Output : Test Stream
```

Hope it will help you to solute your problem.

> Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$phpArray= json_decode($array['streams'],true);
print_r($phpArray);
foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) { 
    echo "<p>$key | $value</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use given code :

```
     if(!empty($array['streams'])){
       $phpArray= json_decode($array['streams'],true);
       print_r($phpArray);
    }
```